Crowdstrike anti-virus not working on server since domain move
I have some servers in my company that were recently moved to another domain as the existing domain they were on is being decommissioned. Since the servers got moved, the Crowdstrike anti-virus that is installed on the server has stopped working. I have contacted Crowdstrike support and they have said that it's the group policy settings that are causing this, whereby there are two separate keys for TLS 1.2 (which Crowdstrike uses to communicate). However, I have many other servers that have this setting and Crowdstrike is able to work successfully.

As you can see in the screenshot, the (Default) key for TLS 1.2 is set to REG_DWORD. Crowdstrike support advised me that it should be set to a REG_SZ word.
Other servers have TLS 1.2 client set to REG_SZ and Crowdstrike works successfully.
Is anyone able to advise further on how to resolve this?

Try it and find out? They know more about the behavior of their product. The original Windows registry did not have any values, only keys. Associated with each key was a 16-bit string that contained a value for something. Also note that the Group Policy settings relevant here are registry values, not the legacy Default unnamed value.
